# Connect to MySql using IP address

Tags: mysql, visual-c++

I have written some code and am currently running it using loachost however am trying to set it up so that I can run the app from other computers, I am using MySql and after searching online I found that if I replace "localhost" with my IP address (found from google) for the host name on MySql I will be able to connect from other machines, I tried this and got an error saying that I cannot connect to the server and listed some checks:

Check that MySql is running on the servr - how do I check this?

Check that MySql is running on port 3306 - I changed this to 3307 when making the database however, I tried both and got the same errors.

Check if root has rights to the IP address from your address - I am running this from the same computer and it has worked fine with localhost so I dont know why it wouldnt but how would I check this?

Make sure you are providing password - I did when I tried to connect to the database and got this error.

Could someone please help me, I have been searching for hours and cant find how to fix this.

Comment: Please view the tag wiki for tags like [tag:sql-server] before including them in questions that obviously have nothing to do with SQL Server.

Comment: I apologize, I will make sure that I check the wiki next time I post a question. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grant access to the account `root@%`.

`root@localhost` and `root@%` are two different accounts. When you're using `localhost` as the hostname, and specify user name `root`, you use `root@localhost`.

When connecting using an external IP, you need to grant database access for `root@%`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it was this and the mistake I had made with the IP address which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
use mysql;
select user,host from user;
update user set host = '%' where user = 'root';
```

and then restart mysql

Comment: Can you add some explanation how this can solve the issue